# Цикличное выполнение ajax на click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, фильтры

Есть вот такой вызов ajax, который работает по клику на option

```
$('#option-test').click(function() {
$('#catalog-form').ajaxSubmit({
    success: function(data) {
        $('#width-from').replaceWith($(data).find('#width-from'));
                }
            });
        });
$('#option-test_2').click(function() {
$('#catalog-form').ajaxSubmit({
    success: function(data) {
        $('#lengh-from').replaceWith($(data).find('#lengh-from'));
                }
            });
        });
```

От двух этих параметров зависит вывод результата (полагаю, можно назвать это подобием фильтра из двух параметров, так же по submit идет запрос в БД), проблема в том, что два ajax этих работают независимо друг от друга, если только я не вложу один ajax в другой:

```
    $('#option-test').click(function() {
$('#catalog-form').ajaxSubmit({
    success: function(data) {
        $('#width-from').replaceWith($(data).find('#width-from'));


 $('#option-test_2').click(function() {
$('#catalog-form').ajaxSubmit({
    success: function(data) {
        $('#lengh-from').replaceWith($(data).find('#lengh-from'));
                }
            });
        }); }
            });
        });
```

Но и в этом случае, я получаю некоректный результат: уже отфильтрованные товары по параметру option-test я могу "фильтровать" по второму параметру лишь единично. После чего выполнение ajax останавливается. В голову залезла мысль создать дикий цикл - вложить друг в друга ajax-ы, но выходит все то же самое - в какой-то момент выполнение по клику не происходит (после N выполнений, где N - количество вложенных друг в друга ajax-ов). Вопрос: есть ли способ сделать выполнение цикличным, то есть - в любой момент по клику на любой из options будет выполняться "фильтр" товаров.

Comment: У вас проблема не в ajax а в самой логике. Надо не ajax после ajax отправлять, надо просто сразу все параметры через 1 запрос передавать и обрабатывать его, соответственно

Comment: Можно чуточку подробнее, в какое направление смотреть хотя бы?